# Using because when the reason isn't a sentence?

Tags: translation, word-choice

An example `Because of the noise, she became startled/surprised.`

Would it be something like `おとから、かのじょはおどろきになった.`? Where I use `から` for because.

Comment: `かのじょはおどろきになった` --> is strange/incorrect. You'd say 「かのじょはおどろいた」/「かのじょはびっくりした」

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't compose it like that. Since おと itself is a mere object and not <s>an event or</s> nature of something, the combination with から doesn't mean reason.

Instead, it should be おと（の せい）で びっくりした.

Comment: You mean おと is a phenomena, an object of perception?

Answer (score 1):

Noun + から　(not a real sentence) can be used to show the noun is the cause of basis for what comes after, used in sentences like:

ちょっとした不注意から大きな事故になることも少なくない。(big accidents are often caused by just a little carelessness)( example taken fromニューアプローチ中上級日本語　p165)

So it is used for cause and effect, but more for showing the basis of judgement, or describing phenomena in general.
I think for a simple kind of 'she was surprised by the noise/because of the noise' type situation it may be more natural to use で instead